Does Tomcat user have to actually own the GeoTIFF files in order to create an image mosaic with it in GeoServer?
We have a server that has our GeoServer data directory on it, but also an NFS mounted to the server to hold large directories of GeoTIFFs for making image mosaics. We are having difficulty making image mosaics when the data lives on the NFS mount due to seeming permissions errors.
First, we have been able to use subsets of this data to make image mosaics if we put it in the GeoServer data directory locally on the server, so this isn't a configuration issue in terms of the image mosaic configuration files or things of that nature.
On the machine that holds all the files that make up the NFS:

We have a user group called cloud with a gid of 47000
We have a user called dev_user
The dev_user owns everything in the entire directory/subdirectory/files chain.
The group is set to cloud on everything in the entire directory/subdirectory/files chain
Directories have drwxrwxr-x permissions
Files have -rwxrwxr-x permissions

On our local machine (the one with the geoserver data directory):

We have created the group called cloud with a gid of 47000
We added the user tomcat to the group cloud
The tomcat user does not have a login

Since both machines have the same group and the group has read/write permissions on the files, I thought I would be able to create the image mosaic using the tomcat user that GeoServer runs as. Unfortunately that doesn't work as expected. Oddly, when I sudo -u tomcat bash on the local machine and go into the directory where the GeoTIFFs live on the NFS mount, I can read, create, and delete files just fine. If I create a file, the user is listed as tomcat and the group is listed as tomcat.
We also briefly chmod 777 on the entire directory/subdirectory/files chain of the NFS and if we did that, we found we could create the Image Mosaic and the sample_image.dat and <mosaic dir>.properties files were created, owned by tomcat with a group of tomcat.
So it seems to be that GeoServer is somehow ignoring group-based permissions and only respecting user-based ones. That leads me to think that tomcat must own all the GeoTIFF files and that dev_user cannot. If this is true, is there any other workaround to this? We're unable to use chown to change the ownership of the files to tomcat as root is mapped to nobody user on the NFS machine.
I receive this error in GeoTools Developer logging. GeoServer/tomcat seems to think that it cannot write to the directory even though I am able to as tomcat using sudo -u tomcat bash:
25 Oct 18:59:49 ERROR  [gce.imagemosaic] - Unable to create the mosaic, check the location:
location is: /files/test/annual_vic4tmax
location exists:true
location is a directory:true
location is writable:false
location is readable:true
location is hidden:false

Any suggestions?

did you restart tomcat after adding it to the group? and/or the machine - groups are funny about when they are set

We did not restart, but I am fairly certain the group took anyway. Prior to setting the group, the tomcat user couldn't write there and after we set it, it could, but only if we went through sudo -u tomcat bash. It wouldn't write if GeoServer was running the show for some reason.

New shells for the tomcat user would pick up the group, the running tomcat process would not unless you restarted at least the process and possibly the machine

also groups are strange on NFS mounts as they follow the host machine not the one mounting the disks

@Ian Turton - went and tested this this morning since our VM rebooted overnight; you are correct, now as long as the tomcat user is part of the group that has read/write permissions for the NFS, whether it owns the directory with .tif files in it or not, it can publish the image mosaic. Thanks! I've updated my answer to reflect correct info as not to confuse people later, but since it's you're answer you can submit and I will be happy to mark it correct.

We've come to the conclusion that tomcat does need to own the directory that contains all the GeoTIFFs in order to create an image mosaic from them. The solution was staring us right in the face - even though our tomcat user doesn't have a true login we could use sudo -u tomcat bash and move the files to the NFS mount as the tomcat user. Then the files are already owned by tomcat and no chown privilege is necessary after they have been moved.
After we rebooted the VM, GeoServer was able to utilize the new group that tomcat was added to (cloud) and able to create image mosaics. To sum up, the important things to check are:

You have a group with the same name and group ID on both the NFS machine and your other server.
The group has read/write permissions in the NFS mount.
The user that runs GeoServer has been added to the group.
To get GeoServer user (e.g. tomcat) to "see" the change in group, first try just restarting the GeoServer process (for us, this was done by restarting the Tomcat service with systemctl restart tomcat).
If the above doesn't work, reboot the server where you added your GeoServer user to the new group. For us, the full reboot was necessary.

